# How to handle binary data in the browser when using byte range requests to server

Tags: javascript, browser, binaryfiles, binary-data

I'm experimenting with controlled file requests. The browser will use byte-range requests to fetch pieces of large files from the server. This could be a video file or a large data file of some sort. I've been able to set up a simple fetch using the `request` module to fetch a range of data.

```
request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080' + file.path, 
    headers: {
        'Range' : 'bytes=0-50'
    }
}, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log('err: ', err);
    console.log('status: ', res.statusCode);
    console.log('body: ', body);
});
```

And this produces the following output:

```
err:  null
status:  206
body:  ftypisomisomavc1.��moovlmvhdК{�К{
```

So, I'm getting the data, however I'm unsure of the best way to handle this binary data and preserve it's integrity. Specifically:

1. Loading it in as binary data, so I can continue to piece together the chunks and eventually provide a downloadable file to the user.
2. Performing some type of checksum or integrity check on the incoming data (assuming I could get an md5 of each chunk, perhaps as a prefetched list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was due to the fact that I was using the `request` module, which does not interface with the native browser XMLHttpRequest API, and therefor cannot request binary data. I made a simple little `request` function which wraps the XMLHttpRequest API and gives me back binary data (`blob`).

```
function request (url, _opt, cb) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var opt = {
        method: 'GET'
    };
    if (typeof _opt === 'function') {
        cb = _opt;
    } else {
        opt = _opt;
    }
    opt.method = (opt.method) ? opt.method : 'GET';
    xhr.open(opt.method, url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    if (typeof opt.headers === 'object') {
        var keys = Object.keys(opt.headers);
        for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(keys[i], opt.headers[keys[i]]);
        }
    }

    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if ((this.status >= 200) && (this.status < 299)) {
            // get binary data as a response
            cb(null, this, this.response);
        } else {
            cb('received error code: ' + this.status, this);
        }
    };

    xhr.send();
}
```

and can use it like this:

```
request(file.path, {
    headers: {
        'Range' : file.range
    }
}, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) { throw new Error(err) ; }
    var contentType = res.getResponseHeader ("Content-Type");
    cb(contentType, body);
});
```